# How to understand “leverage our creativity”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence I have read:

> After we discipline ourselves to adopt the attitude of a champion,
> commit to focus and analysis and leverage our creativity, we must take
> action.

commit is a verb, and focus, analysis, and leverage are the nouns that are committed to. But why does “our creativity” follow with “leverage”?
How can I understand it?

Comment: "leverage" is being used as a verb, meaning "exercise leverage (of)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage is used as a verb also. This is a definition of leverage as a verb from Longman.

> 2 to spread or use resources (=money, skills, buildings etc that an
> organization has available), ideas etc again in several different ways
> or in different parts of a company, system etc

So 'leverage our creativity' means to use creativity.

You may interpret the sentence by splitting in the following way:

> (After we discipline ourselves
>
> //to adopt the attitude of a champion,
>
> //commit to focus and analysis
>
> //and leverage our creativity,)
>
> //we must take action.